# How to solve (a+b)-(r+s) in eval() in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, eval

I am making a certain code for `console` for a certain website that checks a specific element(element contains a string like: ***23+43+54*** or ***(21+3)-5***), puts it in the `eval()` function of Javascript and `console.log`s the result:

```
let answer = eval(document.getElementsByClassName("ques_desc")[0].childNodes[0].textContent);
console.log(answer);
```

Sometimes, however `answer` gets a string like: ***(16+27)-(36+43)***.
In this case although the question is correct, I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical
<anonymous> debugger eval code:1
```

At this point execution of any further lines of code stops, even if I wrap my code in curly braces as we do in maths it doesn't work, what do I do to solve such questions?

Comment: show the html so we can make it runnable. My guess `textContent` is not all the text you expect it is.

Comment: @epascarello the `textContent` provides me with the question, so I think that's enough

Comment: Are you sure? `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("ques_desc")[0].childNodes[0].textContent)` Are you sure it is all the code? We can only guess at your problem with the information you provided.

Comment: Well did you ever debug it like I mentioned??? Still would have been nice to get HTML example of what fails.

Answer (score 0):

The `missing ) in parenthetical` error means that you somehow forgot to write a ")" in your code.

Idk, but take this code for example:

`eval("7 * ((15 / 2.3333 % 25) + -21");`

It should generate an error because it is missing a single ")". But if you try this code:

`eval("7 * ((15 / 2.3333 % 25) + -21)");`

The statement doesn't generate an error.

Note: it is highly recommended not to use eval especially in user input, as hackers can easily use this to hack your website (or Web app).

Answer (score -1):

This is solution to problem

```
    var calculate = function(s, start = 0, end = s.length - 1, map = findParentheses(s)) {
    const nums = [];
    let op = 1;
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
      if (s[i] === '(') {
        const result = calculate(s, i + 1, map[i] - 1, map);
        nums.push(op * result);
        i = map[i];
      } else if (s[i] === '+') {
           op = 1;
      } else if (s[i] === '-') {
           op = -1;
      } else if (isNumber(s[i])) {
           const str = parseNum(s, i);
           const result = parseInt(str);
           nums.push(op * result);
           i += str.length - 1;
      }
      if (nums.length >= 2) {
         const result = nums.shift() + nums.shift();
         nums.push(result);
      }
    }
    return nums.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0);
  };

  function isNumber(str) {
    return /[0-9]+/.test(str);
  }

  function parseNum(s, start) {
    let i = start;
    let output = '';
    while (isNumber(s[i])) {
      output += s[i];
      i += 1;
    }
    return output;
  }

  function findParentheses(s) {
    const map = {};
    const stack = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
      if (s[i] === '(') {
        stack.push(i);
      } else if (s[i] === ')') {
          const left = stack.pop();
          map[left] = i;
      }
    }
    return map;
  }
```

Add this solving code to your problem this will evaluate you problem.

Comment: I am a bit new to JS so pl guide, where do I pass the question? What is the start and end at line 4?
P.S. (16+27)-(36+43) can also be of multiplication or division like:(12*22)/(32+33)

Comment: This is the method to evaluate string expression of addition and substraction. Call method **Calculate** to the text field where you want answer to the expression inserted by user in an input field. Like let solve_exps = document.getElementById('myinput').childNodes[0].textContent    and then console.log(Calculate(solve_exps)) to view answer to the expression after evaluation. This is what I understand through you code. Do upvote if your doubt has been cleared.

Comment: What do I do if I want to extend this function to process multiplications and divisions like: (32*22)-(45*76), because these are usually the types I get.